# copy configuration from x64 to x86

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

when I wrote my solution, it was only for x64. Now I want to start make it compatible for x86 as well. How do I copy all setting from the x64 platform to x86?

I tried the "Configuration Manager. over there I can create new solution platform, but it doesn't apply for each project. For each project you can choose only x64\x86\ASM and that's it

I expect to copy all the setting from x64 to x86 in the best way possible

Comment: You could intentionally remove the x86 platform with Build > Configuration Manager > "Active solution platforms" combobox > Edit > Remove button.  And add it back, using the x64 settings as the source.  Some day they'll hopefully fix the Win32 vs x86 bug, not today.

Comment: I tried that as well. If I remove "x86" and then create "Win32" the properties for each project stays the same for the Win32 option. If I delete for each project the "Win32" and do the same thing - it seems like it destroys the Win32 option - it doesnt have a "build" option anymore. In both ways it doesnt work

Comment: That's pretty vague.  Time to use a text editor, Notepad will do to modify the content of the .vcxproj file.

Comment: I hoped not to get there. But it seems like thats my only option for now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its almost like what Hans offered, "You could intentionally remove the x86 platform with Build > Configuration Manager > "Active solution platforms" combobox > Edit > Remove button. And add it back, using the x64 settings as the source"

but you also need to go to each project in the "configuration manager" windows, remove the "win32" option and add it again. A bit weird but it works!